# "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Currently focused window has been closed" while trying to switchTo().frame() in IE9 browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-9, selenium-iedriver

Couldn't see iframes on right click on IE:9 browser though frames present and for the same page able to identify frames on Firefox browser. While *driver.switchTo().frame("frMiftButton");* is added in script, saw error 'Currently focused window has been closed'

```
package eHMS_package;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;


public class HMS_Login_entry_Frame {

    public WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:/SRIKANTH/IEDriverServer_32bit/IEDriverServer.exe");
        InternetExplorerDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to("http://10.1.0.20:8080/JHMS/login.faces");
        driver.findElement(By.id("frmLogin:txtUserName")).sendKeys("makella");
        driver.findElement(By.id("frmLogin:txtPassword")).sendKeys("sriram");
        driver.findElement(By.name("frmLogin:login")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        int size = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe")).size();

        System.out.println("Total Frames --" + size);
        // prints the total number of frames 

        driver.switchTo().frame("frMiftButton"); 
        System.out.println (driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div")).getText()); 

    }
}
```

Console error :

```
 Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)`enter code here`
    3.9.0.0
    Listening on port 12876
    Only local connections are allowed
    Apr 16, 2018 4:14:28 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
    INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
    Total Frames --0
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Currently focused window has been closed.
    Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:42:28.403Z'
    System info: host: 'FINSOL211', ip: '10.1.0.23', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
    Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 9, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:12876/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
    Session ID: 6942842a-984d-4b10-bcd4-57ab8c48f29d
    *** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=frame[name='frMiftButton'],iframe[name='frMiftButton']}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:160)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:398)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:469)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElements(By.java:441)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:359)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.frame(RemoteWebDriver.java:933)
        at eHMS_package.HMS_Login_entry_Frame.main(HMS_Login_entry_Frame.java:39)
```

Comment: Could anyone please suggest on why the frames are not identified in IE-9 browser using inspect option, though frames are present and able to inspect and see iframes on FireFox browser

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to consider as follows :

- When you work with **Selenium**, [**InternetExplorerDriver**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) and **Internet Explorer** you have to mandatory setup the environment as per the [**Required Configuration**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration).
- As you are seeing **Total Frames --0** possibly no *frames* are rendered through *Internet Explorer 9 Browser*. At this point it is worth to mention that different browsers renders the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) differently. In this case it may be a design/architecture issue which you need to take up with your *Project Management*.
- If you are sure about the presence of the *frame* **frMiftButton** available when browsing *Manually* of-coarse you are trying to detect the frames and switch over too early. In the previous line as you have invoked `click()`, on the new page you should induce *WebDriverwait* for the intended *frame* to be available to switch and you have to switch either through *frameID*, *framename*, etc as follows :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("frMiftButton")));
  // or
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.name("frMiftButton")));
  ```
- You are using *Selenium Java Client v3.9.1* and *IEDriverServer v3.9.0.0*. there was a major issue with *IEDriverServer v3.9.0.0* and you can find the detailed discussion in [**Selenium Java Client (v3.9.1) with IEDriverServer v3.9.0.0 (64-bit) crashes with org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:28286**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5519). In this case you need to use the latest **IEDriverServer v3.11.1**